# Correct way to measure a timeout in Java 8 time API

Tags: java

In Java....
What is an easy, understandable and correct way to measure a timeout in the presence of time corrections (e.g. the system clock is adjusted to a central clock).

```
long limit = System.currentMillis() + Duration.ofSeconds(1).toMillis();
while( true ){
    // do some actions
    if( limit <= System.currentMillis())
        break; // timeout
}
```

This code is *not* robust, because if the system's clock is adjusted in parallel, the timeout might be shorter/longer.

Better to use `System.nanoTime()`

```
long limit = System.nanoTime() + Duration.ofSeconds(1).toNanos();
while( true ){
    // do some actions
    if(( limit - System.nanoTime()) > 0 )
        break; // timeout
}
```

Now it is agnostic to system clock adjustments.

Now with `java.time` API

```
var limit = Instant.now().plusSeconds(1);
while( true ){
    // do some actions
    if( Instant.now().isAfter(limit) )
        break; // timeout
}
```

Better readable as the `nanoTime()`, but again not stable for system clock adjustments.
Is there a way to write it with `java.time` API, readable, easy, but be agnostic to system clock adjustment at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, none of your approaches is not correct. But your requirement that the timer (the clock) should be secured from external manipulation means that only the version based on `System::nanoTime` is valid.

Also your statement that the version based on `Instant` is easiest to understand is true. So combine the two:

Create your own implementation of `java.time.Clock` that uses `System::nanoTime` to return an instance of `Instant` through `Clock::instant`.

Then you use your third option:

```java
public class YourClass
{
  static Clock m_TheClock = new YourClock();
  /*
   * For test purposes: YourClass.m_TheClock = Clock.fixed( … );
   */
  public static final Duration TIMEOUT_VALUE = Duration.ofSeconds( 1 );
  
  …
  var limit = Instant.now( m_TheClock ).plus( TIMEOUT_VALUE );
  ForeverLoop: while( true )
  {
    // do some actions …
    if( Instant.now( m_TheClock ).isAfter( limit ) ) break ForeverLoop;
  }  //  ForeverLoop:
}
```

As you implemented the clock yourself, it is safe from manipulation from the outside (clock adjustments, daylight savings time switching …), and for testing purposes, you can provide a clock that responds according to you testing needs (seconds that take ages, or will lapse in no time …)

An implementation of `Clock::instant` could look like this:

```java
@Override
public final Instant instant()
{
  var nanoTime = System.nanoTime();
  var epochSecond = nanoTime / 1_000_000_000;
  var nanoAdjustment = nanoTime % 1_000_000_000;
  var retValue = Instant.ofEpochSecond( epochSecond, nanoAdjustment );
  
  return retValue;
}
```

Of course, the `Instant` returned by this method does not have much in common with the current time, but for the calculation of the timeout expiration it is more than sufficient.